# excel lookup with multiple answers

Tags: excel

How do I work out a formula to give me the results of the most days visited? eg. 1040 came in monday, tuesday and friday.

```
Member  Spend  Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday

1040    $100   0      2      2       1         1        2      1
11509   $300   1      0      0       3         1        1      2
1178    $500   1      0      3       3         2        0      0
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are looking for, but how about something like =COUNTIF(C1:IV1,">0")

Comment: The results from formulas can come in all shapes and sizes. You've offered no indication on what you want to do with the results once you've retrieved them.

Comment: pls mark my answer as your solution if it helped you (mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). thanks

Answer (score 0):

As little help for the beginning use the function `CONCATENATE` with `MAX`, e.g.

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A2=MAX(A2:G2);A1;);IF(B2=MAX(A2:G2);B1;))
```

and so on for the rest of your needed cells

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:G2,1),A2:G2,0)))&", "&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:G2,2),A2:G2,0)))&", "&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(LARGE(A2:G2,3),A2:G2,0)))`

[image]